# How to generate a JUnit xml report from MonkeyTalk runner (command line)?

Tags: xml, junit, jenkins, report, monkeytalk

I'm running my tests (using monkeytalkpro-runner-2.0.1.beta).

```
java -jar monkeytalkpro-runner-2.0.1.beta.jar -agent iOS -host <device ip> myTest.mt -reportdir ./testresults -verbose
```

The tests are running fine as expected, (same from the IDE).

I don't get a xml (JUnit style) in order to integrate into jenkins. I'm getting a html+xml file (but not JUnit style).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my question.

The JUnit xml report is create **ONLY** when you are running a Suite, a single test will not create any JUnit xml report.

I can't find any documentation about that.